# How to `unstring` an object wrapped in a string without calling it?

Tags: php, laravel

I have an array with values that are objects wrapped as strings, how can I turn them back into objects without calling them? `['randomNumber' => '$this->faker->randomNumber()']`

This array is being passed into a stub (writing a php file):

```
$replace = [
    '{{mappedResult}}' => var_export($mappedResults, 1),
];
```

instead of getting this array:

```
$mappedResults = ['randomNumber' => $this->faker->randomNumber()]
```

I get this array instead:

```
$mappedResults = ['randomNumber' => '$this->faker->randomNumber()']
```

Comment: That is not "objects wrapped as strings", it is a piece of PHP code.

Comment: @miken32 how do you remove the quotes?

Comment: You don't; there are no quotes, it's just a string.

Comment: @miken32 please re-read, there is a detailed question, I know the abstract structure of a string, the question is not about values, but a technical question of transforming a string into an object after going through `var_export()`.

Comment: What is the intent behind using `var_export()`? This appears to be a design flaw that might be implemented better if we had more context to provide an alternative approach.

Comment: Your intent is unclear, your terminology is confusing (how is `$this->faker->randomNumber()` an object?) and this all really sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Describe what it is you're actually trying to achieve and we might have a suggestion.

Comment: @El_Vanja `$this` is an object. Not an XY problem, this has to do with Laravel stubs

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the return value of the method call as the value in the map, you can use `eval`:

```
foreach ($mappedResults as $key => $value)
    $mappedResults[$key] = eval($value)
```

Note `eval` returns NULL unless a return statement is called in the code string. Then the value passed to return is returned. If there is a parse error in the code string, eval() returns FALSE.

Hence you don't want to call and evaluate the code and based on my understanding you want to recreate the php file, you should use a custom export function that can remove quotations:

```
function export($input) {
    $response = [];
    foreach($input as $key => $value)
        $response[] = var_export($key, true) . " => " . $value;
    return "[".implode(",",$response)."]";
}
```

Comment: not really , but close: `array (... , ..., 6 => '\'customer_id\' => $this->faker->randomNumber()',);`

Comment: @clusterBuddy can you please tell me what is the problem? I get this result: ['randomNumber' => $this->faker->randomNumber()]

Comment: Sure, when I pass this to the stub it shows as the array (sent you in previous comment). This has to do with stubs in Laravel.

Comment: @clusterBuddy apparently. Sorry I have no idea about the stubs and Laravel.